# Converting DataFrame String column containing missing values to Date in Julia

Tags: date, dataframe, julia, missing-data

I'm trying to convert a DataFrame String column to Date format in Julia, but if the column contains missing values an error is produced:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Int64(::Missing)
```

The code I've tried to run (which works for columns with no missing data) is:

```
df_pp[:tod] = Date.(df_pp[:tod], DateFormat("d/m/y"));
```

Other lines of code I have tried are:

```
df_pp[:tod] = Date.(passmissing(df_pp[:tod]), DateFormat("d/m/y"));
df_pp[.!ismissing.(df_pp[:tod]), :tod] = Date.(df_pp[:tod], DateFormat("d/m/y"));
```

The code relates to a column named `tod` in a data frame named `df_pp`. Both the `DataFrames` & `Dates` packages have been loaded prior to attempting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `passmissing` way is

```
df_pp.tod = passmissing(x->Date(x, DateFormat("d/m/y"))).(df_pp.tod)
```

What happens here is this: `passmissing` takes a function, and returns a new function that handles `missing`s (by returning `missing`). Inside the bracket, in `x->Date(x, DateFormat("d/m/y"))` I define a new, anonymous function, that calls the `Date` function with the appropriate `DateFormat`. 
Finally, I use the function returned by `passmissing` immediately on `df_pp.tod`, using a `.` to broadcast along the column.
It's easier to see the syntax if I split it up:

```
myDate(x) = Date(x, DateFormat("d/m/y"))
Date_accepting_missing = passmissing(myDate)
df_pp[:tod] = Date_accepting_missing.(df_pp[:tod])
```

Comment: Many thanks. rewrote it as:
`df_pp[:tod] = passmissing(x->Date(x, DateFormat("d/m/y"))).(df_pp[:tod]);`
for consistency, but it works! Hopefully soon I'll understand the syntax a little better.

Comment: I've added some explanation - does that make it clearer?